# Does the growth rate of SPY published by morningstar include the dividend yield

Tags: stocks, dividends, yield, growth

According to [morningstar](http://performance.morningstar.com/funds/etf/total-returns.action?t=spy)

the growth rate for SPY in 2014 was 13.46%.

Does this include the dividend yield of SPY ~1.87% or do we need to add this number to the 13.46?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That includes the dividend yield.

From Morningstar directly:

> Annual Returns
>
> Annual total returns are calculated on a calendar-year and
>   year-to-date basis. Total return includes both capital appreciation
>   and dividends. The year-to-date return is updated daily.
>
> For mutual funds, return includes both income (in the form of
>   dividends or interest payments) and capital gains or losses (the
>   increase or decrease in the value of a security).

Source: http://www.morningstar.com/InvGlossary/annual_returns.aspx

And anecdotally:

> Although most financial media sources will list 11.74% as the S&P 500
>   index's return in 2014, an investor reinvesting dividends in the S&P
>   500 would have theoretically done even better: 14.04%.

Source: http://seekingalpha.com/article/2791755-2014-s-and-p-500-return

Comment: oops..why do i need to reinvest the dividends to get better yield? if the stock returns 11% in capital appreciation and the yield is 3%, then my ROI is 11 = 3 = 14% regardless of whether i reinvest, correct? I guess i am ignoring interest and inflation, but generally speaking.

Comment: Reinvested dividends benefit from the stock growth, and they earn more dividends, which earn more dividends, etc. Compounding!

Comment: Thanks. One more question...this yield is after the S&P fees,correct?